# Remove all KEYS from Redis where VALUE match pattern

Tags: redis, xargs, redis-cluster

I have a Redis multicluster with 2 types of records:

```
4_123: 123
// and
123: 4_123
```

I'm removed records matching `4_*` by KEY using:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern 4_* | xargs -n 1 redis-cli DEL
```

there also address params for an exact cluster, that is why I used `xargs -n 1 ...` to avoid wrong cluster error.

Now my question is how can I delete records with VALUE matching this same pattern: `'4_*'`?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've come up with so far is:

```
for i in $(redis-cli KEYS '?[^_]*'); do
  MYVAL=$(redis-cli GET $i);
  if [[ "$MYVAL" == "4_"*  ]];then
    redis-cli DEL $i;
  fi;
done
```